# Blogdown site not rendering in R

Tags: r, blogdown

I am trying to create a website using the `blogdown` package. When I try to execute the following code

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'gcushen/hugo-academic')
```

I get the following error

```
Error: "C:\Users\user\Documents\finale\website\content\home\demo.md:39:1": failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "alert" not found
Error: "C:\Users\user\Documents\finale\website\content\home\demo.md:39:1": failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "alert" not found
Error: "C:\Users\user\Documents\finale\website\content\home\demo.md:39:1": failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "alert" not found
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" convert toYAML --unsafe' execution failed with error code 65535
```

any way to fix this issue?

TIA!

Comment: Looks like the Github repo was recently moved. I'm investigating now.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie, let me know if you manage to find it!

Comment: Yes, I found a solution in another post (marked above).